# Why is an OverflowException raised in this situation?

Tags: c#, casting, overflowexception

Why isn't this code idempotent?

```
double.Parse(double.MinValue.ToString())
```

This will throw an `OverflowException` with the message

> Value was either too large or too small for a Double

I would expect this expression to result in a `double` whose value was equal to `double.MinValue`.  What is the reason it fails?

Comment: @HansPassant, makes sense, but unfortunate in terms of "pit of success" criteria...  But thanks for sharing.